# Bloquear que outros sites carreguem minhas imagens

Tags: nginx

Como faço no nginx bloquear que outros dominios carreguem minhas imagens?

Comment: O que você procura é uma forma de proibir o `Hotlinking`, procure por `HTTP_REFERER`, existem algumas técnicas para evitar isso.

Answer (score 0):

Uma estratégia para o que você quer, seria criar uma página intermediara para carregar suas imagens, com isso você consegue detectar a origem da solicitação, abaixo vou colocar um exemplo em PHP.

```
<?php
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'http://www.seusite.com.br') === 0 && isset($_GET['img'])){
    $name = './imagens/' . $_GET['img'];
    $fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

    header("Content-Type: " . mime_content_type($name));
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

    fpassthru($fp);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Exemplo de uma página sua utilizando a imagem:

```
<img src="imagens.php?img=icone.jpg" />
```

Para ser mais efeito você tem que bloquear no apache o acesso direto a pasta de imagens e seus arquivos.